# Django ModelForm booleanfield Required field is not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I do not know why does not work but it is very simple example

**models.py**

```
class Reg(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=u'Мероприятие')
    #первый автор
    fam_author = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Фамилия автора' )
    name_author = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'Имя автора' )
    ot_author = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Отчество автора' )
    no_ot = models.BooleanField(blank=True,verbose_name=u'Для граждан, не имеющих отчество по паспорту, отметить галочкой следующее поле')
    ...................
    personal = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Согласие на обработку и использование персональных данных')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Автор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Автор'

    class Admin:
        pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s (%s)' % (self.fam_author, self.name_author)
```

**forms.py**

```
class GenForm11(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reg
        exclude = ('event')
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^kras/', ContactWizard.as_view([GenForm11, GenForm31, GenForms4, GenForms5, GenForms6, GenForms7])),
```

pytnon manage.py syncdb

in admin sreenshot

[image]

in website
[image]

Why could this be? several times removed from the base model and created again

UPD1

**python manage.py sqlall**

```
CREATE TABLE `reg_reg` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `event_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `fam_author` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `name_author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `ot_author` varchar(200),
    `no_ot` bool NOT NULL,
    `birth_author` date NOT NULL,
    `tel_m_author` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `tel_r_author` varchar(15),
    `tel_d_author` varchar(15),
    `email_author` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    `email_d_author` varchar(75),
    `text_author` longtext,
    `facultet_diplom` varchar(50),
    `napravl_diplom` varchar(50),
    `kurs_diplom` varchar(50),
    `group_diplom` varchar(50),
    `text_diplom` longtext,
    `post_diplom` varchar(200),
    `sec` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `personal` bool NOT NULL
)
;
```

`personal` bool NOT NULL

:(

Comment: could you please try to clarify what is is that isn't working

Comment: The most recent field can not celebrate, but the condition (blank = True) Partner code
Then you can fill the field should be mandatory, but it is in the admin part is not in bold, as required.

and on the website, if you click "send" field is not there, that it necessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"required" does work - it's a BooleanField which defaults to `False` and not null.
Having it unchecked is a valid value (False).

You can override the clean() method to make sure it's set to true. For example:

```
class Reg(models.Model):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if not self.personal:
            raise ValidationError('CUSTOM ERROR HERE')
```

Or validate it in the form:

```
class GenForm11(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reg
        exclude = ('event')

    def clean_personal(self):
        personal = self.cleaned_data['personal']

        if not personal:
            raise ValidationError('CUSTOM ERROR HERE')

        return personal
```

Comment: so as to make it required for filling
To validate this form pointing to it as the box above

or just write an extra check?

Comment: You should add a check that `personal==True` either in the model by overriding the `clean` field, or in the form.

Comment: FormWizard for this apparently is not enough, he has successfully transferred to the second step: (

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please see my update to the answer, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 2):

models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    def clean(self):
        if not self.personal:
            raise ValidationError('blah')
```

or you can validate it in Form...